# folium Choropleth world map: default values for countries

Tags: python, leaflet, data-visualization, geography, folium

I am using a [GeoJSON world map](https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/tree/master/countries) and [`folium` to  build a choropleth map](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html):

```
the_map = folium.Map(tiles="cartodbpositron")
the_map.choropleth(
    geo_data=country_shapes,
    name='choropleth',
    data=orders_by_country,
    columns=['country', 'orders'],
    key_on='feature.id',
    fill_color='Blues',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
)
the_map
```

The result I am getting shows all countries that do not appear in the dataframe shaded in deep blue, which is the color of the highest values. Why? Is it possible to set a default value?

[image]

Comment: Maybe try a color palette like `BuGn` instead of `Blues`

Comment: Different color, same problem.

Comment: Sorry, not much help on this one.  It would be nice to have a default color of some kind

Comment: Check out my answer. I ran into the same problem when trying to modify the example from the [folium quickstart](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Choropleth-maps) guide.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your `key_on` value to: **`key_on='feature.properties.name'`** instead of `key_on='feature.id`

Assuming you're getting your `country_shapes` using the following:

```py
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/master/examples/data'
country_shapes = f'{url}/world-countries.json'
```

The keys of the dictionary located in the json file at [github.com/python-visualization/folium/tree/master/examples/data/world-countries.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/master/examples/data/world-countries.json) determine what you should use for the `key_on` value.

i.e. (from `world-countries.json`):

> {"type":"Feature",**"properties"**:{**"name"**:"Afghanistan"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[61.210817,35.650072],...

According to the **Choropleth** class definition in the [folium documentation](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#module-folium.features):

> **key_on** *(string, default None)* – Variable in the geo_data GeoJSON file to bind the data to. Must start with ‘feature’ and be in JavaScript objection notation. Ex:
>   ‘feature.id’ or
>   ‘feature.properties.statename’.

Answer (score 1):

Folium 0.8 has new properties for choropleth maps. Please check the documentation [folium documentation](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#module-folium.features).
`nan_fill_color` should be able to solve your problem.

```
the_map = folium.Map(tiles="cartodbpositron")
the_map.choropleth(
    geo_data=country_shapes,
    name='choropleth',
    data=orders_by_country,
    columns=['country', 'orders'],
    key_on='feature.id',
    fill_color='Blues',
    nan_fill_color='white',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    line_opacity=0.2,
)
the_map
```